# .bat file sorting files into folders by name

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file, directory

I was wondering if someone could help me edit an answer to the previous question:

[.bat file sorting files into folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654270/bat-file-sorting-files-into-folders)

I want to do something similar to that code. I want to sort files into folders using a section of the name, except rather than using the last 10 characters I want to use the 10th to the 20th character of the name. Thanks for any help!

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
set f=%%a
set g=!f:~0,10!
md "!g!" 2>nul
move "%%a" "!g!"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`set g=!f:~0,10!` takes a substring, starting from the first one (starts counting at `0`!), with the length of 10.

If you want to start with the tenth char, keeping the lenght of ten, use
`set g=!f:~9,10!`

See `set /?` for more information.